# Iterating efficiently over objects

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

I have designed my own classes in Python as follows:

```
class Main:
    def __init__(self):
        self.list = list() # Contains TestA objects

class TestA:
    def __init__(self, start_time, end_time):
        self.elements = list() # Contains TestB objects
        self.start_time = start_time
        self.end_time = end_time

class TestB:
    def __init__(self, timestamp):
        self.timestamp = timestamp
```

The list of the `Main` class contains objects of `TestA` class and the list in `TestA` class contains objects of `TestB` class. An example is the following:

```
testB1 = TestB(121)
testB2 = TestB(155)
testB3 = TestB(891)
testB4 = TestB(901)

testA1 = TestA(100, 200)
testA1.elements.append(testB1)
testA1.elements.append(testB2)

testA2 = TestA(500, 1000)
testA2.elements.append(testB3)
testA2.elements.append(testB4)


main = Main()
main.list.append(testA1)
main.list.append(testA2)
```

Now I would like to filter objects based on timestamps. First, I would like to retrieve all `TestA` objects which have the `TestA.start_time` and `TestA.end_time` in a specific range. Second, I would like to retrieve all `TestB` objects which have the `TestB.timestamps` in a given range. Of course, I could just loop over all `TestA` and `TestB` objects but this is inefficient if there are a lot of objects.

Is there a more efficient way to do it?

Comment: "Of course, I could just loop over all TestA and TestB objects but this is inefficient if there are a lot of objects. Is there a more efficient way to do it?" no, not if you are going to use lists to store this information. How else do you imagine this would be possible? Have you actually tried and profiled the performance?

Comment: Yes, there are more efficient ways of doing this, _if_ you're willing to store the objects in a data structure other than a plain list.

Comment: binary search, if the lists are sorted by timestamps

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga If he could imagine how this is possible, he most likely wouldn't ask. Duh.

Comment: There are lots of ways. The only one that is simple to achieve, though, is to sort the arrays, and then do a divide-and-conquer search for the start and end times. That is still super slow if you continuously insert new items, but if you only insert once, then sort, then retrieve, it is pretty much the fastest way. Everything else would involve writing a custom data structure, I'd go for some type of binary tree.

Comment: @Sanyash there's a nesting structure, so not sure how that would work. Maybe just keep two sorted list of *all* A and B objects.

Comment: Why do you think iteration is inefficient? You should be able to traverse objects in O(n) under ideal conditions. Do you have the same Bs stored in multiple As? How many objects do you have to begin with?

Comment: @finomnis a btree with an index, although, that really suggests that the OP should just use a database instead of re-inventing that wheel.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Yes, database, 100% agree. Especially if he is at the point where he has enough data that he actually has to think about complexity.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use a pandas [dataframe](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html),
with an index on the timestamp column.
Then, if you have a million entries but only request twenty-four matching rows,
only a couple dozen rows will be examined.